# error using mv to rename files in shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename, mv

I am trying to rename all files in a directory using `mv` but it isn't working. My code is:

```
id= '29 10 15'
for zzvar in ${id} ; do
  mv /media/storage/DTI/vgcross_sj${var}* /media/storage/DTI/vgcross_SJ${var}*
done
```

Even when I take the loop out and just try the command with one subject, I get the error:

```
mv: target:/media/storage/DTI/vgcross_SJ  is not a directory.
```

Obviously it's not a directory, because that's what I'm trying to rename the file as! 
Do you have any ideas as to why it's not working?

Comment: You are using * there, which expands to multiple files, including directories. So after expansion you what mv command will see is a whole list of items that you're trying to move somewhere, and it's not a directory. In general, your script looks a bit messy, `id= '29 10 15'` shouldn't have space after = sign,  within script you're referencing ${var}, while your loop uses zzvar

Comment: Is there a way I can include all files that begin with vgcross_sj without including the directories? In other words, a similar function to using * that it would understand?

Thank you!